# Rearranging information from data frame in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following df, which was obtained from a excel file:

```
df1 <- data.frame( Colour = c("Green","Red","Blue"), 
                   Code = c("N","U", "U"), 
                   User1 = c("John","Brad","Peter"), 
                   User2 = c("Meg","Meg","John"), 
                   User3= c("", "Lucy", ""))
```

I need to rearrange it in order to obtain a data frame where all names are listed in the first column (only once) and the colors (and respective codes) appear in the following columns, as shown:

```
df2 <- data.frame(User=c("John","Brad","Peter","Meg","Lucy"),
                  Color1 = c("Green","Red","Blue","Green","Red"),
                  Code1 = c("N","U","U","N","U"), 
                  Color2=c("Blue","","","Red",""),
                  Code2=c("U","","","U",""))
```

I´d appreciate some help. Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not pretty, but here's another solution in pure base R that uses a couple of calls to `reshape()`:

```
reshape(transform(subset(reshape(df1,varying=grep('^User',names(df1)),dir='l',v.names='User'),User!=''),id=NULL,time=ave(c(User),User,FUN=seq_along),User=factor(User)),dir='w',idvar='User',sep='');
##      User Colour1 Code1 Colour2 Code2
## 1.1  John   Green     N    Blue     U
## 2.1  Brad     Red     U    <NA>  <NA>
## 3.1 Peter    Blue     U    <NA>  <NA>
## 1.2   Meg   Green     N     Red     U
## 2.3  Lucy     Red     U    <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate to post this because of the conceptual similarity with @akrun's answer, but you can do this also with `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package along with `reshape` from base R.

```
library(splitstackshape)
reshape(
  getanID(
    merged.stack(df1, var.stubs = "User", sep = "var.stubs")[User != ""], 
    "User"), 
  direction = "wide", idvar = "User", timevar = ".id", drop = ".time_1")
#     User Colour.1 Code.1 Colour.2 Code.2
# 1: Peter     Blue      U       NA     NA
# 2:  John     Blue      U    Green      N
# 3:   Meg    Green      N      Red      U
# 4:  Brad      Red      U       NA     NA
# 5:  Lucy      Red      U       NA     NA
```

---

`merged.stack` makes the data long, `getanID` creates an ID variable to be used when going to a wide form, `reshape` does the actual transformation from this semi-wide form to a wide form.

---

This was the best I could think of for the "dplyr" + "tidyr" users. Seems quite verbose, but shouldn't be too hard to follow:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  gather(var, User, User1:User3) %>%      # Get the data into a long form
  filter(User != "") %>%                  # Drop empty rows
  group_by(User) %>%                      # Group by User
  mutate(Id = sequence(n())) %>%          # Create a new id variable
  gather(var2, value, Colour, Code) %>%   # Go long a second time
  unite(Key, var2, Id) %>%                # Combine values to create a key
  spread(Key, value, fill = "")           # Convert back to a wide form
# Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
# 
#     var  User Code_1 Code_2 Colour_1 Colour_2
# 1 User1  Brad      U             Red         
# 2 User1  John      N           Green         
# 3 User1 Peter      U            Blue         
# 4 User2  John             U              Blue
# 5 User2   Meg      N      U    Green      Red
# 6 User3  Lucy      U             Red
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table`, i.e. v1.9.5+.  It can take multiple `value.var` columns.  We convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(df1)`), `melt` the data with id columns as 'Colour' and 'Code', remove the rows where 'User' is not equal to '' (`[User!='']`), create a grouping sequence based on the 'User' column and `dcast`.  The instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var=c('Colour', 'Code'), 
           value.name='User')[User!=''][,
              N:=1:.N, User], User~N, value.var=c('Colour', 'Code'))
#    User 1_Colour 2_Colour 1_Code 2_Code
#1:  Brad      Red       NA      U     NA
#2:  John    Green     Blue      N      U
#3:  Lucy      Red       NA      U     NA
#4:   Meg    Green      Red      N      U
#5: Peter     Blue       NA      U     NA
```

Or as @Arun mentioned in the comments, we can make use of the `subset` argument in `dcast` instead of `[User!='']`

```
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var=c('Colour', 'Code'), 
             value.name='User')[,N:= 1:.N, User],
       subset=.(User !=''), User~N, value.var=c('Colour', 'Code'))
#    User 1_Colour 2_Colour 1_Code 2_Code
#1:  Brad      Red       NA      U     NA
#2:  John    Green     Blue      N      U
#3:  Lucy      Red       NA      U     NA
#4:   Meg    Green      Red      N      U
#5: Peter     Blue       NA      U     NA
```

Comment: you can use `subset = .(User != "")` directly in `dcast`